# Evaluate: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin({a y)}}{\sinh{(\pi y)}}\cos({b\sqrt{1 + y^2})}\, dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I have been trying to solve the following integral:

$$I(a,b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin({a y)}}{\sinh{(\pi y)}}\cos({b\sqrt{1 + y^2})} ~ dy$$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. I have tried the following approaches:

1. Assuming the partial derivatives of $I(a,b)$, we may transform the evaluation of that integral to this differential equation problem:
   $$\dfrac{\partial^{2}I(a,b)}{\partial b^{2}} = \dfrac{\partial^{2}I(a,b)}{\partial a^{2}} - I(a,b) $$ with $I(a,0) = \tanh(a), I(0,b) = 0$ and $I_{b}(a,0) = 0$. However, Mathematica gives as solution the definition of I(a,b).
2. Another approach was to write
   $$I(x,t) =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin({a y)}}{\sinh{(\pi y)}} \cos(b) ~ dy  + \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin({a y)}}{\sinh{(\pi y)}}(\cos({b\sqrt{1 + y^2})} - \cos(b)) ~ dy $$
   since the first integral is straightforward. Now I should solve the second integral under some assumption, but got nothing.

I would appreciate any help with the integration. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Judging by recent movements, your post will be quickly closed and possibly deleted as it stands, I am sad to say. I suggest you edit your post with some more context: this integral surely came up in some class or some textbook, and you will have learnt how to approach similar examples. You should show us your attempts and what you know how to do, you may as well try a semicircular or rectangular contour (with a keyhole at $y=0$ and $y=i$) and see where it goes

Comment: Please don't delete your questions. It makes no sense. Just edit them instead. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4591456/evaluate-int-0-infty-dfrac-sina-sinhx-sinh-pi-sinhx-co

Comment: Zero reason for this post to be deleted or closed.